# Checking if an Error Type Occurred After Running A Hypotheis Test - Split (A/B) Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, ab-test

When doing Split (A/B) Testing, or really any other Statistical Hypothesis test for that matter, there is always some chance of committing a Type 1 or Type 2 error.  I am wondering if there are any tests that would help to determine whether a Type 1 or Type 2 error was committed after having run a test and made a decision of whether to reject or fail to reject the null.

This is a bit of a broad and open ended question, but in terms of something like Split (A/B) Testing where there are two online ads and we want to see which ad generates more revenue, if we run the test and determine that (with some level of confidence) we fail to reject the null (there is no significantly significant difference in revenue generation between the two), if we then gather data on the online ad that is implemented is there a way to determine, with a decent amount of confidence, that a Type 2 error has been committed (conversely for a Type 1 error after having rejected the null)

My gut feeling is to run an A/A test that bootstraps a random sample from the time periods where only 1 of the ads were running.

I am also wondering if this entire process will increase the probability of completing a type 1 or type 2 error overall (separately or together)

Answer (score 0):

> if there are any tests that would help to determine whether a Type 1 or Type 2 error was committed after having run a test and made a decision of whether to reject or fail to reject the null.

If you rejected, you can't have made a type II and if you didn't reject, you can't have made a type I.

Outside of that, if you used the best available test for your alternative of interest (given your assumptions), there's really no way to get more information out of the data you used.

So you're left with gathering another sample and testing again.

But if you're going to do that, if the null is true, then the chance of at least one type I error is increased (roughly, to the sum of your two type I errors). On the other hand, if the null is false, the chance of at least one type II error is increased. If you can afford a larger sample, better to plan your tradeoff of type I and type II errors optimally from the start rather than try to second guess your decision.

And in practice, what could you tell from a second test? Imagine you collect a second sample and your two samples give different decisions. One of those decisions was certainly wrong, but you now no good way to tell which one.

Are you going to try to combine them somehow? If you're going to do that, why not plan the larger study from the outset and combine the information optimally?

> if we then gather data on the online ad that is implemented is there a way to determine, with a decent amount of confidence, that a Type 2 error has been committed

I'm not 100% clear what you mean ... you no longer have something to compare it to. With some strong assumptions, you're increasing the size of one of your two groups, but not the other

> My gut feeling is to run an A/A test that bootstraps a random sample from the time periods where only 1 of the ads were running.

Again, with some heroic assumptions, you're basically trying to do the "run a second test" which has the problems I mentioned above. But there's more -- let's say from that new B and old A sample (both not overlapping your A/B test) you conclude that they're different. Is that because they're really different or because the assumption that you can really compare them fails for some reason?

> I am also wondering if this entire process will increase the probability of completing a type 1 or type 2 error overall (separately or together)

You haven't clearly identified the overall decision process, so it makes it hard to figure out what the effects are for whatever it is you want to do, but as indicated before, even when they're comparable, the chance of at least one type I or at least one type II error in the two tests will go up.